# Null Object Reference with Custom Array List. Where to instantiate?

Tags: java, android, instantiation

Really hit a wall trying to complete my estimations project.  Would like to save a custom ArrayList to sharedPreferences with gson.  I need to add the estimate to the estimates (a custom  ArrayList).  I've read a dozen other similar posts and even conquered a similar problem before.  I've been going crazy try to figure out what I'm not instantiating correctly and where I should be doing this instead.  I feel like I tried everywhere but I'm obviously missing something.

The problem is with the .add() in the code below.

```
          saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                estimates.add(newEstimate);
                saveData();
            }
        });
```

Here's the Activity in full

```
        
public class EstimateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView eRecyclerview;
    private CartAdapter eAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Inventory> eCartList;
    private TextView clientName, clientEmail, workOrder;
    private Button saveButton;
    private ArrayList<Estimate> estimates;
    private Estimate newEstimate;
    private String name, code, email;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estimate);
        estimates = new ArrayList<>();
        newEstimate = new Estimate();

        //get intents
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        newEstimate = intent.getParcelableExtra("newEstimate");
        estimates = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("estimates");
        eCartList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("cartList");

        //set up textViews
        workOrder= findViewById(R.id.cart_work_order);
        clientName = findViewById(R.id.client_name_cart);
        clientEmail = findViewById(R.id.cart_email);

         name = newEstimate.getClientName();
        code = newEstimate.getWorkOrder();
        email = newEstimate.getClientEmail();

        workOrder.setText(code);
        clientName.setText(name);
        clientEmail.setText(email);

        //connect recyclerView
        eRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_cart);
        eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        eAdapter = new CartAdapter(eCartList);
        eRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
        eRecyclerview.setAdapter(eAdapter);
        newEstimate.setCart(eCartList);

        //Set up save button
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                estimates.add(newEstimate);
                saveData();
            }
        });


    }


    private void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("share preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(estimates);
        editor.putString("task list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the logcat and error line.

Comment: Will do when I get back to the computer. The error is a null object in the line estimates.add(newEstimate)

Comment: are you sure `estimates = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("estimates");` is working  as expected ?

Comment: How is the activity started? The intent might not have the expected payload, which would end up with `estimates` (and other fields) being `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Estimate, Inventory Class have to implement Parcelable interface.**

According to [Android API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable), You have to `describeContents()` and `writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)` correctly.

and also do null check after `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra()`.